# Load array of pairs from application.yml

Tags: spring-boot, kotlin, yaml

The task is to fill list of pairs from application.yml file.
So in my kotlin code I've got something like this:

```
@Component
class LocalImageStore(
@Value("\${images.thumbnails_sizes}")
private val thumbnailsSizes: List<Pair<Int, Int>>
) : ImageStore
{
// unrelated code here
}
```

Inside of `application.yml` file I've got following:

```
images:
  dir:
    path: images
  thumbnails_sizes: 
    - [150, 150]
    - [200, 200]
    - [400, 450]
```

So I expected that my `thumbnailsSizes` will contain the list of pairs from the .yml file, but all I see is error message `Could not resolve placeholder 'images.thumbnails_sizes' in value "${images.thumbnails_sizes}"n`
I didn't find the way I can store list of pairs in .yml file, so please advise how to do it in a right way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try the following approaches:

```yaml
images:
  dir:
    path: images
  thumbnails_sizes: 
    - 150: 150
    - 200: 200
    - 400: 450
```

Or

```yaml
images:
  dir:
    path: images
  thumbnails_sizes: 
    - { 150: 150 }
    - { 200: 200 }
    - { 400: 450 }
```

---

Use a configuration class instead of `@Value` directly. Assuming that you have the following classes for these properties:

```kotlin
@ConstructorBinding
@ConfigurationProperties(prefix = "images")
class ImagesConfiguration(@field:NestedConfigurationProperty val thumbnailsSizes: List<ThumbnailSize>)

data class ThumbnailSize(val width: Int, val height: Int)
```

And you change the `LocalImageStore` to the following:

```kotlin
@Component
class LocalImageStore(private val imagesConfiguration: ImagesConfiguration) : ImageStore {
  // just use imagesConfiguration.thumbnailsSizes were needed
  // unrelated code here 
}
```

You can easily configure this in YAML as follows:

```yaml
images:
  dir:
    path: images
  thumbnails-sizes: 
    - width: 150
      height: 150
    - width: 200
      height: 200
    - width: 400
      height: 450
```

Comment: As I understand, yaml file should store pairs in key: value format? And in my case it is not like key: value, it is more like `{["width": 150, "height": 150], ["width": 200, "height": 200], ["width": 400, "height": 450]}`. Should I then create class for storing width-height pairs and parse somehow json array from the .yml file?

Comment: It would be easier and more readable to do it with a class yes.

Comment: I've edited my answer, please check it ;)

Comment: Still see the error: `Could not resolve placeholder 'images.thumbnails_sizes' in value "${images.thumbnails_sizes}"`

Comment: I've updated my answer. Take a look ;)

Comment: I've managed to start it, however `imagesConfiguration.thumbnailsSizes` is empty. Also it is underlined by IntelliJ IDEA with message `Could not autowire. No beans of 'ThumbnailSize' or 'List<ThumbnailSize>' types found.`

Comment: You must not autowire `ThumbnailSize` or `List<ThumbnailSize>`, but `ImagesConfiguration` in `LocalImageStore` as my answer suggests. You might need to add `@ConfigurationPropertiesScan` to your main class (the one with `@SpringBootApplication`). Give it a try and let me know the outcome ;)